# What is the best way to smoothen a noisy image filter?

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl, image-processing, shader, hlsl

I am currently trying to recreate the watercolor effect of Instagram in Unity.

Instagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJAo6.jpg

My approach: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngnn3.jpg

My approach is rather noisy. This is the main code which creates the effect:

```
float3 stepColor(float3 col){
     const float3 lumvals = float3(0.5,0.7,1.0);

    float3 hsv = rgb2hsv(col);
    if(hsv.z <= 0.33){
        hsv.z = lumvals.x;
    }
    else if(hsv.z <= 0.55){
        hsv.z = lumvals.y;
    }
    else{
        hsv.z = lumvals.z;
    }
    return hsv2rgb(hsv);
}
```

Which algorithm would be suitable here to denoise and smoothen the end result as Instagram is achieving it?

Comment: Instead of using a single luminance value, use a kernel to get the final luminance of the fragment by sampling the fragment itself and it s neighbours and weight-average them

Comment: There are lots of differences, none of them are due to noise. This filter is quite a bit more complicated than what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watercolor filters use something called *mean shift analysis* to average out the image while preserving features. It is an iterative approach where you make clusters of pixels gravitate towards their mean value.

Here is a java code example:
https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/plugins/mean-shift.html

Here is a paper which describes the watercolor effect and its components (including edge darkening):
http://maverick.inria.fr/Publications/2006/BKTS06/watercolor.pdf

There is a github project with CUDA and OpenCL implementations, but if you want to actually understand the algorithm, i'd refer you to this page which explains it quite neatly using python code:

http://www.chioka.in/meanshift-algorithm-for-the-rest-of-us-python/

Another option from the top of my head is to use a Sobel/Roberts cross filter to detect all the borders in the image, and then use the inverse of this value as a mask for a gaussian blur. It won't give you the same nice layering effect though.